# Can Visual Studio warning messages be selectively purged?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, compiler-warnings

Is there any way I can purge certain warning messages in Visual Studio 2010 (or 2012 for that matter). In some instances VS complains that a given CSS property is not known, even though such properties are applicable for certain browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can use

```
#pragma warning( disable : number_of_the_warning )
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can find a list of the compiler warnings that are off by default.